# Add a watermark to a PDF without installing new software

Tags: pdf

Can I add a watermark to a PDF without installing additional software?

Ideally, I'd like to do it using a shell script or something but appreciate manual processes at this time too.

Answer (score 1):

Automator can do this with Preview's Watermark PDF Documents action. You can create this workflow as a service to receive a PDF document and add a watermark to it.

[image]

Comment: This is useful. Thank you. Can you advise on settings to get the watermark centered horizontally and vertically and from bottom left to top right? I tried a few things - unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Vishal Adjust the offset depending on your image and page, you can just enter numbers and see it reflected in the preview ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrpbC.png)).